# Find Average Score to Date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a student table as below;

```
CREATE TABLE exam_scores
(
 student_id text,
 exam_date date,
 exam_score int
 );
 
insert into exam_scores
Values
('a001','2018-03-29',75),
('a001','2018-04-25',89),
('b002','2018-02-24',91);
```

I am trying to create a view such as;

| student_id | exam_date | max_score_to_date | avg_score_to_date | max_score_ever |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a001 | 2018-03-29 | 75 | 75 | 89 |
| a001 | 2018-04-25 | 89 | 82 | 89 |
| b002 | 2018-02-24 | 91 | 91 | 91 |

I can calculate all aggregated columns except "avg_score_to_date". I have my query below. Can you please help me modify my code, so it works correctly to calculate the average score to date?

```
SELECT
     student_id
    ,exam_date
    ,MAX(exam_score) OVER(Partition by student_id,exam_date) AS max_score_to_date
    ,AVG(exam_score) OVER(Partition by student_id,exam_date) avg_score_to_date
    ,MAX(exam_score) OVER(Partition by student_id) AS max_score_ever
 FROM exam_scores
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to do the group by student and add order by exam_date.

```
    SELECT
         student_id
        ,exam_date
        ,MAX(exam_score) OVER(Partition by student_id,exam_date) AS max_score_to_date
        ,AVG(exam_score) OVER(Partition by student_id order by exam_date) avg_score_to_date
        ,MAX(exam_score) OVER(Partition by student_id) AS max_score_ever
     FROM exam_scores;
```

[image: Query Output:]